# Getting an actor by name from ActorSystem or Context (Akka.NET)

Tags: actor, akka.net

Is it possible to check if an actor exists in ActorSystem?

I just don't want to pass IActorRef reference to every actors constructor and would like to have something like GetOrCreate method to instantiate the required actor. So it could be like a singleton actor which I would use throughout the actor system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check existence of any actor using [ActorSelection](https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/addressing.html#absolute-vs-relative-paths) to ask it to identify itself:

```cs
var selection = Context.ActorSelection(actorPath);
/// if there's no actor, this operation can timeout
var reply = await selection.Ask<ActorIdentity>(new Identify(null), timeout);
```

While this works everywhere, even across network boundaries, you cannot "just" create an actor from anywhere. In order to be created actor needs a parent - either an actor system or another actor.

Get or create logic can be done quite simply from inside of an actor:

```cs
IActorRef GetOrCreate(string childName)
{
    var child = Context.Child(childName);
    if (Equals(child, ActorRefs.Nobody))
        child = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ChildActor()), childName);
    return child;
}
```

If you need to make it work in distributed environment, this functionality is covered by [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/) plugin.

Comment: This approach is fine, but I need to keep the actor Path once it's created the first time and that is reminding of the global static context which is not the best thing to do for the actor and cluster environment or maybe I get this wrong? Is it fine to keep the thread-safe static storage and create the required actor once it's required checking the actor path

Comment: Common thing for that is just to retrieve `IActorRef` once and cache it in somewhere  closer to actual place that has to use it - it's very common to have an actor with a dictionary of key=>IActorRef to other actors spread across the system. Ofc actors can be stopped - in that case IActorRef will be invalidated. This is something solved by [watching](https://getakka.net/articles/remoting/deathwatch.html): it works for both local and remote actors.

Answer (score 0):

ActorSelection has a method named "ResolveOne" for check existence of an actor. According to documentation:

> Resolves the IActorRef matching this selection. The result is returned
>   as a Task that is completed with the IActorRef if such an actor
>   exists. It is completed with failure ActorNotFoundException if no such
>   actor exists or the identification didn't complete within the supplied
>   timeout

This method can be used like this:

```
var actorRef = await Context.ActorSelection("Path of Actor !").ResolveOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```